# PhpStorm: How by means of the hotkeys to jump the cursor for braces?

Tags: phpstorm, hotkeys

How by means of the hotkeys to jump the cursor for braces? Arrows do this is not convenient since I type blind by touch typing method.

```
function abc($x)
{
    if($x <= 2) {
    return $x; | <---- cursor here
   } | <-- how to jump here? (hot keys) (Notepad++ ctrl+\+\ forth, ctrl+/ - back)
}
```

More precisely in Notepad++ this movement was one word forward or backward.

Is there something similar in PhpStorm? Or am I alone all over the world typing touch typing?

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear. In a sense -- do you just want to jump to the next line (as per your simple example) ... or to the closing `}` even if it's few lines below (e.g. has few more lines with code)? Because in second case it's easy -- `Ctrl+]` should do the job. If not -- `Settings | Keymap` and check or assign another shortcut for `Move Caret to Code Block End` action -- it will place caret just before closing `}` for that block.

Comment: no it's not that. For example, in notepad ++, ctrl + \ allows you to move Caret one word forward, and ctrl + / back
Is there something similar in phpstorm?

Comment: For me `Ctr+\ ` or `Ctrl+/` in Notepad++ behaves like standard `Ctrl+Arrow Right/Left`. What commands those shortcuts are associated to in Notepad++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move forward/backward by word, use `Ctrl+Left` and `Ctrl+Right` arrows - this works in most editors, though what each editor considers a "word break" may be different (some consider "_" to break words and some don't, for example).

To move to the opening brace or the closing brace for the current block, use `Ctrl+[` or `Ctrl+]`.

Comment: I just redefined Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right on ctrl+enter and ctrl+\ Thank you!